# Kubernetes aggregation certificates - apiserver client authentication allowed names

Tags: kubernetes

Definitions I'm using in this question:

- Main apiserver: the core kube-apiserver
- Extension apiserver: an addon like metrics-server

I am reading through the [configure aggregation layer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/configure-aggregation-layer/) guide and I don't understand the *main* apiserver's use of `--requestheader-allowed-names`. In section [Kubernetes Apiserver Client Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/configure-aggregation-layer/#kubernetes-apiserver-client-authentication) it says:

> The connection must be made using a client certificate whose CN is one of those listed in --requestheader-allowed-names. Note: You can set this option to blank as --requestheader-allowed-names="". This will indicate to an extension apiserver that any CN is acceptable.

It makes it sound like the *main* apiserver is responsible for setting this. Surely the *extension* apiserver would be in control of this and determine what is acceptable? Why configure this on the *main* apiserver at all? I.e. The client certificate common names are what they are and it's up to the *extension* apiserver to accept/reject these?

Or is that doc section mixing options that are passed to both the *main* and *extension* apiservers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand now why the *main* kube-apiserver needs this allowed names list: The kube-apiserver is a *frontend* for all the extension apiservers. So the requests always go through kube-apiserver first; it *aggregates* the requests and then passes them onto the correct backend extension apiserver. Hence it'll need to know which CN's to accept. I.e. a request to an extension server would go:

```
client request -> kube-apiserver -> extension-apiserver
```

The extension apiserver would then also check the CN once it received the request after it was routed there by main kube-apiserver.